# Purpose of RxJavaPlugins.onSubscribe method

Tags: rx-java2

Can you explain purpose of RxJavaPlugins.onSubscribe method in subscribe method of Observable class? Inputs are Observable and Observer and result is Observer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It allows wrapping the downstream `Observer` into a custom `Observer`, allows considering the upstream source's type for the wrapping and at the end, return the wrapper `Observer` to be subscribed to the upstream.

You can shim behavior after specific operators this way for diagnostic purposes.